# Exit If Statement if returned value is not a boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a user input for a yes or no answer. I would like to construct a function in python 3 which I could pass the value like `isTrue('yes')` and then the function would return `True` and `isTrue('no')` would return `False`. I am aware that I could just use an if statement to see if the value is just `yes` or `no`, but for other reasons, I'd benefit from using a function like `isTrue()`. Creating the function `isTrue()` is very easy, but the part I am struggling with is how to handle a value that is not true, nor false, like `maybe` or `IDK`. Ideally, I'd like to have an if statement like so

```py
if isTrue(userInput) '''Some code here that would run anther function if the value was not true or false''':
    print('Input was Ture')
else:
    print('Input was False')
```

Is there a way I could return a value that I could still have the same if statement structure, but detect if the value wasn't `True` or `False` without having to do something like this and somehow have it integrated with the `True` if statement?

```
if isTrue(userInput):
    print('Input was Ture')
else !isTrue(userInput):
    print('Input was False')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Comment: Your function needs to have three possible returns. True and False are obvious, but it also needs to have a third state, which could be "raise ValueError(userInput)" or just "return None". Without three possible states, you can't check for three possible states.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I currently have it return none if its neither true nor false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this problem like so:

```
def isTrue(value):
    truthy_values = {'yes', 'true', 'True', ...}
    return value in truthy_values

def isFalse(value):
    falsey_values = {'no', 'false', 'False', ...}
    return value in falsey_values

def isBool(value):
    return isTrue(value) or isFalse(value)
```

The difficulty in your case is mostly that you have non-standard definitions of what counts as `True` or `False`. A basic approach would be to make sets of the values you consider truthy or falsey, and check if the given value is in them - and if it's in neither, then it's not a boolean, and you can do with that what you will. You could also expand the definitions of `isTrue()` and `isFalse()` to cover entire classes of values (e.g. if input is a list and its length is greater than 0).

In this case you can easily check whether something is True, False, Neither, or any combination thereof, with just one call:

```
if isTrue(userInput): ...      # input is explicitly true
if isFalse(userInput): ...     # input is explicitly false
if not isBool(userInput): ...  # input is indeterminate
if not isTrue(userInput): ...  # input is at least not true, might be indeterminate
if not isFalse(userInput): ... # input is at least not false, might be indeterminate
```

at which point you could just do a simple `if` block:

```
if isTrue(userInput):
    print('Input was True')
elif isFalse(userInput):
    print('Input was False')
else:
    print('Invalid Repsonse')
```

Comment: Thanks, this fits directly into my script and works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

in boolean there is only True or False. but in the isTrue method if you are returning None then you can do this.

```
if isTrue(userInput)== True:
    print('Input was Ture')
elif isTrue(userInput) == False:
    print('Input was False')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Comment: @Daniel - you are right, thank you for that. I think I can check explicitly if its True or False to overcome that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Green Cloak Guy's answer was a bit more informative and complete which is why I accepted it over yours, again thanks for the answer

Comment: @Jack Stoller - sure!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have three possible states, you really need three possible return values. You could return True, False or None, but it makes more sense to raise a ValueError. That is also helpful for logging or displaying error messages if you put a reason in the ValueError.

```
truthy_values = {'yes', 'y', 't', 'true', '1'}
falsey_values = {'no', 'n', 'f', 'false', '0'}

def isTrue(userInput):
    value = userInput.strip().lower()
    if value in truthy_values:
        return True
    if value in falsey_values:
        return False
    raise ValueError('isTrue could not understand ' + userInput)
```

Demonstrating this function in action, with an exception handler:

```
def evaluate_input(userInput):
    try:
        if (isTrue(userInput)):
            print ('Input was True')
        else:
            print ('Input was False')
    except ValueError as e:
        print ('Invalid input:', str(e))

evaluate_input('True')
evaluate_input('No')
evaluate_input('Potato')
```

> Input was True
>   Input was False
>   Invalid input: isTrue could not understand Potato